# Dealing with Webhooks in Flask or FASTAPI

Tags: python, flask

The concepts of webhooks are quite simple, yet I am here for some guidance.
Consider a webhook program in FLASK:

```
@app.route('/webhook', methods = ['POST'])
def webhook():
    data = json.loads(request.data)

    return data
```

Such a program will easy return a json POST request. And result will look like this:

```
{
"passphrase": "SkZSV1YwZz0=",
"timenow": "2021-09-15T21:18:00Z",
"item": "apple",
"quantity": "50",
"account": "9999"
}
```

Now I have successfully read in the webhook data. Next step is to do something with the data.
Say  I would like to search my database `'df'` for `item: apple` and return the price.

```
def get_item_price(df, item_name):
    # Returns price by filtering df.
    df = df[df['name'] == item_name]
    df.reset_index(inplace = True)
    price = df['price']
    return price
```

So, `price_of_item = get_item_price(df, item_name)` can now be used.

I can see if I implement the function above I can get the price of the apple but cant proceed further on how to use that price. Say I have a home page where i would like to render the price of apple.

```
@app.route("/")
def index():
    return index_template.format(message = price_of_item)

index_template = """
    <div> the price of apple is: {message} </div>
    """
```

But since webhook is a **POST** request url I cant get values out of it. I can save the *price_of_item* on a file and read it but thats pointless. Any help with filling out this missing link would be really helpful.

Comment: I have project experiences with Django, Flask, Sanic, Tornado, FastAPI. And I suggest you to try this one: https://github.com/tiangolo/fastapi

Comment: ok how would you do this with fastapi?

Comment: Here is a demo:   https://github.com/waketzheng/fastapi-tortoise-pytest-demo.git

Answer (score 0):

Ok after some tutorial hunting, I have come up with 2 solutions:

1. Create a database or file to store the values and read them as and when they get updated outside the webhook route. See here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_sqlite.htm
2. Set the price_of_the_item as cookies and then get the cookies from the home page.
   Best described here: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/flask/flask_cookies.htm

Comment: Cookies won't work - they'll only be available to the browser, and a webhook is meant to be called from another service when an event happens; i.e. outside of the browser context.